# Directive priority with event listener

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, angularjs-directive, angularjs-compile

I have one input element with 2 directives:
-direc (priority level 1)
-directive (priority level 0)

even if *direc* is supposed to execute first, *directive* is executing first.
Why?

Here is a snippet to show what is going on

```js
angular.module('app', [])


.directive('direc', function(){
  
  return {
    priority : 1,
    link : function(scope, element){
      
      element.on('click', function(){
          alert('direc');
      });
    
    }
  };  

})

.directive('directive', function(){
  
  return {
    priority : 0,
    link : function(scope, element){
      
      element.on('click', function(){
          alert('directive');
      });
    
    }
  };  

});
```

```html
<div ng-app="app">

   <input type="text" direc directive/>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what happen while directive comes into a picture, angular run the directive `compile` function first.

Here in `compile` you can have a control over a raw DOM / plain DOM, in `compile` function you will not have scope. Compile function is responsible for  returning the `preLink` and `postLink` function. Out of which `preLink` gets called first

Inside `preLink` function you could have DOM is available with scope, Right after the `preLink`, it does render inner element or other directives. After each element of that DOM is traversed it fires the `postLink` function. Which has purely compile DOM with scope. That why the the event of `directive` gets registered first as it have the lowest priority and having its function `postLink`.

[**Plunkr for Understanding Flow**](http://plnkr.co/edit/kXV4xoDOHUCxTv8Sz2wf?p=preview) (Look at console to make it more clear)

You should register those events inside the `preLink` function so that the event gets registered after a compile of directive function gets executed.

**Code**

```
angular.module('app', [])
.directive('direc', function() {
  return {
    priority: 1,
    compile: function(element, attributes) {
      console.log("Compiled direc")
      return {
        pre: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          console.log("Prelink for direc firective generated");
          element.on('click', function() {
            alert('direc');
          });
        },
        post: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          console.log("Called After direc DOM linked with scope")
        }
      }
    },
  }
})
.directive('directive', function() {
  return {
    priority: 0,
    compile: function(element, attributes) {
      console.log("Compiled direc")
      return {
        pre: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          console.log("Prelink for direc firective generated");
          element.on('click', function() {
            alert('directive');
          });
        },
        post: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          console.log("Called After directive DOM linked with scope")
        }
      }
    },
  };
});
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/xBtVov5aePvASRmTzmw6?p=preview)

Comment: Could you comment answear below, so thinks get clear for me and others please?

Answer (score 1):

Per the docs:

> When there are multiple directives defined on a single DOM element, sometimes it is necessary to specify the order in which the directives are applied. **The priority is used to sort the directives before their compile functions get called**. Priority is defined as a number. Directives with greater numerical priority are compiled first. Pre-link functions are also run in priority order, but post-link functions are run in reverse order. The order of directives with the same priority is undefined. The default priority is 0.

I think you're confusing the functionality of priority, as it doesn't relate to which directive's event listeners are called first, but which one runs their link function first.

If you make changes to the element when the link function is executed you can see the difference:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.directive('direc', function(){

  return {
    priority : 1,
    link : function(scope, element){
      element.html('direc with priority 1');

      element.on('click', function(){
        alert('direc');
      });

    }
  };  

})

.directive('directive', function(){

  return {
    priority : 0,
    link : function(scope, element){
      element.html('directive with priority 0');

      element.on('click', function(){
        alert('directive');
      });

    }
  };  

});
```

The element with the lowest priority was the last one to run, hence the resulting HTML is "direc with priority 1"

Here's a working plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/VKqiMQDyMFsFguuRp7Ko?p=preview

Comment: thank you for this example. I understand now, it is only the first execution time that changes. I'm trying to understand why previous answear is working within pre link. There is a contradiction between answears I think